# Spring Security Http Basic not working showing Login Page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have following class to initialize spring security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteHttpAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api/ping");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();

    }
}
```

But, this is showing login page instead of Basic Authentication Popup.
I need Basic Auth, So that I can login it through Postman.

[image]

Comment: Your RemoteHttpAuthenticationProvider is a customized authentication provider ?

Answer (score -1):

Your must return the response header WWW-Authenticate with value "Basic".

Documentation about this response header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate

In the next link there is a complete example:

https://memorynotfound.com/spring-security-basic-authentication-configuration-example/

Comment: Why have this response -1?

Answer (score -1):

You make login page need to authenticated, so it didn't show. It's easy to resolve, just make uri /login not need authenticated.